# cypher distinct is returning duplicate using with parameter

Tags: neo4j, cypher, cypher-3.1

```
MATCH (c:someNode)   WHERE  LOWER(c.erpId) contains (LOWER("1")) 
OR  LOWER(c.constructionYear) contains (LOWER("1")) 
OR  LOWER(c.label) contains (LOWER("1"))
OR  LOWER(c.name) contains (LOWER("1")) 
OR  LOWER(c.description) contains (LOWER("1"))with collect(distinct c) as rows, count(c) as total 
    MATCH (c:someNode)-[adtype:OFFICIAL_someNode_ADDRESS]->(ad:anotherObject) 

WHERE toString(ad.streetAddress) contains "1"     
OR toString(ad.postalCity) contains "1" 
with distinct rows+collect( c) as rows, count(c) +total as total
 UNWIND rows AS part

RETURN part order by part.name SKIP 20 Limit 20
```

When I run the following cypher query it returns duplicate results. Also it the skip does not seem to work. What am I doing worng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `WITH DISTINCT a, b, c` (or `RETURN DISTINCT a, b, c`), that just means that you want each resulting record (`{a: ..., b: ..., c: ...}`) to be distinct -- it does not affect in any way the contents of any lists that may be part of `a`, `b`, or `c`.

Below is a simplified query that might work for you. It does not use the `LOWER()` and `TOSTRING()` functions at all, as they appear to be superfluous. It also only uses a single `MATCH/WHERE` pair to find all the the nodes of interest. The [pattern comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/lists/#cypher-pattern-comprehension) syntax is used as part of the `WHERE` clause to get a non-empty list of `true` value(s) iff there are any `anotherObject` node(s) of interest. Notice that `DISTINCT` is not needed.

```
MATCH (c:someNode)
WHERE
  ANY(
    x IN [c.erpId, c.constructionYear, c.label, c.name, c.description]
    WHERE x CONTAINS "1") OR
  [(c)-[:OFFICIAL_someNode_ADDRESS]->(ad:anotherObject)
    WHERE ad.streetAddress CONTAINS "1" OR ad.postalCity CONTAINS "1"
    | true][0]
RETURN c AS part
ORDER BY part.name SKIP 20 LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: to lower was added to make the query case-insensitive

Comment: Lowercasing "1" does not change its encoding.

Comment: yes the values does not necessary means one it can be any string value since I am generating this query based on some requirements dynamically

Comment: You should pass the comparison value as a parameter, and keep the query itself unchanged. That is faster and more secure. Also, you should pass the lowercase value so that your query does not constantly use the lowercase function for it.